# loading content in a div and not showing styles and scripts

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page that load different pages with ajax. but the other use some script to convert grayscale image effect. [grayscale image hover](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/html5-grayscale-image-hover)
the problems is when it try to load doesnt show the effect 
for example:

in my main page:

```
$(function(){
$("#family").click(function () {
    $("#proyects").load('family.html');
});
});
```

put the content here

```
<div class="ten columns content" id="proyects">

</div>
```

the other page load the grayscale effect, works fine alone but when it loads with ajax doesn't show the effect

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/gray.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <section id="content">
        <article class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/proyecto1.jpg" height="223" width="327"></a>
         </article>
             </section>
```

Comment: Remove `jquery.min.js` on the page you are loading, then move the `gray.js` to after the content.

Comment: removed jquery.min.js on the page family.html and y move gray.js after the content in my main page but nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code sample, there is no `#family` tag when the page is loaded, so making a `click()` call will not bind to anything. If `#family` is populated after the page loads, you should use an `on('click')` call which does proper event binding when the DOM element is actually loaded onto the page. I would also recommend using the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method in favor of `load()` to properly handle AJAX requests.

In other words...

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#family', function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/family.html'
          , dataType: 'html'
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#proyects').append(data);
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: im really new with jquery how can i do that way??

Comment: thanks works fine this way...now i have a problem loading the flex slider in the page doesnt work.. but thanx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this class, but it sounds like the gray.js scrips are being loaded after the page is loaded, but before the images are loaded via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar [not familiar at all] with loading AJAX, but but I have some theories.

Could it be that gray.js isn't loading on the page that family.html is being loaded into? Or if jQuery is called more than once (one time on the page loading family.html and also once in family.html) that could cause some issues.